# how to safely Opens a thread from InkPresenter.StrokesCollected event? DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION

Tags: c#, multithreading, xaml, uwp

the sigsend.AddStrokes(e1) will cause DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION. the sigend is a inkstrokecontainer class instanc in a UWP app .

below is the code:

```
     inkpane.InkPresenter.StrokesCollected += rooPage.snink;
          public async void  snink(InkPresenter sender, InkStrokesCollectedEventArgs args) 
 {  task.run(()=>
                {            sigsend.Clear();
                    sigsend.AddStrokes(e1);
                    var lstream = new MemoryStream();
                    await sigsend.SaveAsync(lstream.AsOutputStream());
                    var siginkbuffer = lstream.ToArray();
                 });
   }
```

the sigend is a inkstrokecontainer.  this will cause  [DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION]

I have try many method, such as use task.run or  Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPool.RunAsync, to makesure the task is run in background instaed of UI Thread, but is usless.  I also try to use task.run to run this code in a background task, and in the backgroun task use and (CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, async () => and etc to run the   sigsend.AddStrokes(e1) to vist the UI thread. But all of them are useless, it always cause  DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION  .

The sigsend is not binding to an inkcanva, I just use it to serialize inkstroke in it.

Why? what is the reason?     I think this is some matter in UI Threading.

**new:**

I have try some other code, found that seems is the **async** **await** method cause this , if

```
  inkpane.InkPresenter.StrokesCollected += rooPage.snink;
                  public **async** void  snink(InkPresenter sender, InkStrokesCollectedEventArgs args)  
{ await task.run(etc.);
}
```

will cause an error.

I have to open an new task, because if the workload in the binding method of InkPresenter.StrokesCollected event is too heavy, it also will cause the DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION. But if I use the await  task.run() and add async to the snink method, it will cause the DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION.

so, the question is , how to Opens a thread safely ?

**new1**  below is simple code, I does not visit UI code in the task.run .ink1 is an inkcanvas UI control in xaml. istring is a json string about 1kb. and run this code, it will cause

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

below is the simple code.

```
public sealed partial class wpage : Page


 {
        public wpage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            ink1.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer = inkStrokeContainer1;
            ink1.InkPresenter.StrokesCollected += InkPresenter_StrokesCollected;
            ink1.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = CoreInputDeviceTypes.Pen | CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse;
         }
 string istring;
 public async void InkPresenter_StrokesCollected(InkPresenter sender, InkStrokesCollectedEventArgs args)

        { 

                await sic(istring);
         }



 public  Task sic (String js)
        {


       var ts =  Task.Run(async () =>
        { 


            using (MemoryStream memoryStream1 = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (StreamWriter streamWriter1 = new StreamWriter(memoryStream1))
                {
                    await streamWriter1.WriteAsync(js);
                    await streamWriter1.FlushAsync();
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream2 = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        Compressor compressor1 = new Compressor(memoryStream2.AsOutputStream(), CompressAlgorithm.Lzms, 32768);
                        await compressor1.WriteAsync(memoryStream1.ToArray().AsBuffer());
                        await compressor1.FinishAsync();

                    }

                }
            }

        });
            return ts;
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi, When this error occurs, you should jump to the **App.g.i.cs** page. You can find the variable named `$exception` in the debug window at the bottom of the Visual Studio interface, which may contain the details of the error, which you can use it to know the cause of your mistake

Comment: @Richard Zhang-MSFT,  ths  App.gics just shows :DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif
        }
    }

Comment: Hi, This is the code, please pay attention to your Visual Studio debug window, as described in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019#inspect-variables-with-the-autos-and-locals-windows), check the variable `$exception`, which has the error details.

Comment: @Richard Zhang-MSFT  I know in most time the vs will show this, but it dose not show it in this time.  The EXCEPTION  seems is cause by the xaml thread.

Comment: @Richard Zhang-MSFT Hi thank you. I write some code in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58653439/how-to-safely-open-an-new-background-task-thread-from-an-inkpresenter-strokescol.  I have tried invoke an action, use or not use Dispatcher.RunAsync, and task.run and many permutation and combination with them. still can't solve the problem.

Comment: @Richard Zhang : Hi,thanks. I add a minimal runnable demo.  This error seems does not cause by binding. Because If I invoke the sic method in other event, such as pointer move, it also will boom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so, the question is , how to Opens a thread safely ?

As you can see from your problem description, you have used `Task.Run` and `CoreDispatcher`, but they have no effect. Have you tried to use both at the same time?

```cs
public async void Test()
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            // code here
        });
    });
}
```

From the code you posted, using only `Task.Run` is to open a new thread, the external thread can not directly access the UI thread, but through the `CoreDispatcher` can access, so the comprehensive use of the two is a good select.

If you want better performance, the Windows Community Toolkit provides the [DispatcherHelper](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/e383eeadb4bdcf07dcca4e2768f806eb2ef732f7/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp/Helpers/DispatcherHelper.cs) class to help you better perform asynchronous programming.

Best regards.

Comment: this method already has been used before I ask, and it will still cause this EXCEPTION.

Comment: the matter is that, it seems, If I use async and await, the xaml thread will boom. you can have a try to InkPresenter.StrokesCollected event, the event is in UWP's input.inking name space.

Comment: Hi thank you. I write some code in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58653439/how-to-safely-open-an-new-background-task-thread-from-an-inkpresenter-strokescol.  I have tried invoke an action, use or not use Dispatcher.RunAsync, and task.run and many permutation and combination with them. still can't solve the problem.

Comment: Hello, please check these: First, do you add `InkCanvas` to the visual tree. Second, whether the `InkCanvas` has been loaded when the event is triggered, this error may cause by bind. If you can provide a minimal runnable demo, this will be very helpful.

Comment: Zhang : Hi,thanks. I add a minimal runnable demo.  This error seems does not cause by binding. Because If I invoke the sic method in other event, such as pointer move, it also will boom.

Comment: Hi, I tested your code, it reported an error, but it has nothing to do with XAML. The problem is on `Compressor`. You used an empty `MemoryStream` in the `Compressor` constructor, but specified a 32kb block size for it. This caused an error. It is recommended that you set the block size to 0 when you create the `Compressor` and the software will call the default block size.

Comment: Zhang-MSFT                very thanks, It prefect avoid the error.